# Google Committed Use Discount and Zone details

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I currently have a Google Compute Engine VM located in Zone `us-central1-a`.  I want to purchase a Committed Use Discount for this VM, but when I visit the signup page, there is no option for `us-central1-a`, the closest being `us-central1`.

Will it be necessary for me to move the instance to `us-central1` using the information [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones), or will the purchase of a commitment in `us-central1` automatically apply to a VM located in `us-central1-a`?

Since I plan to make a 3-year commitment, I don't want to make a mistake because I have heard stories about the lack of support from GCP.

Comment: Do you want to commit CPU/Memory, or GPU /local SSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`us-central1` is the region. `us-central1-a` is a zone within that region. Committed use discounts are per region.

> Committed use discounts work on most Compute Engine machine types,
> including predefined and custom machine types. Committed use discounts
> are simple and flexible, and require no upfront costs. Discounts apply
> to the aggregate number of vCPUs, memory, GPUs, and local SSDs within
> a region, so they are not affected by changes to your instance's
> machine setup.

[Committed use discounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts)

[Google Cloud Video: Committed Use Discounts](https://videolabs.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/#16)